# Swift - drop shadow on the masked image in the table row

Tags: ios, swift

here is a situation.
I've created a storyboard and UIViewController. To UIViewController I've added UITableView. To UITableView I've registered custom TableViewCell in which I need to add a rounded image and drop shadow from it.
I've created UIView and added to it UIImageView. For UIView I've created file with the following code:

```
class drawView: UIView {
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
        return
    }
    self.drawCircle(context)
}
private func drawCircle(_ context: CGContext){
    context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.black.cgColor)
    let newMask = CAShapeLayer()
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
    newMask.path = circlePath.cgPath
    self.layer.mask = newMask //if I comment this line then the shadows works properly, if not, there is no shadows
    self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    self.layer.shadowOffset = .init(width: 10, height: -10)
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 2
}
```

}

How can I make rounded image and rounded shadow from it in the table row?
Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

I made some extensions, check this:

```swift
extension UIView {
    /// Apply corder radius to the view
    /// - parameter radius: The corder radius value applied to view. Default value: 4
    func makeRoundCorner(withRadius radius: CGFloat = 4) {
        clipsToBounds = true
        layer.cornerRadius = radius
    }

    /// Apply shadow to the view
    /// - parameter offset: The offset (in points) of the layer’s shadow. Default value: CGSize(width: 0, height: 2)
    /// - parameter opacity: The opacity of the layer’s shadow. Default value: 0.2
    /// - parameter radius: The blur radius (in points) used to render the layer’s shadow. Default value: 4
    /// - parameter color: The color of the layer’s shadow. Default value: opaque black
    func makeShadow(offset: CGSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2),
                    opacity: Float = 0.2,
                    radius: CGFloat = 4,
                    color: UIColor = UIColor.black) {
        let layer = self.layer
        layer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
        layer.shadowOffset = offset
        layer.shadowRadius = radius
        layer.shadowOpacity = opacity
        clipsToBounds = false
    }
}
```

How to use and the output

```swift
let image = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "test_icon"))
    image.backgroundColor = .red
    image.makeRoundCorner(withRadius: 20)
    image.makeShadow(offset: CGSize(width: 1, height: 1), opacity: 1, radius: 4, color: .black)
```

[image]

Comment: use and output in the UIViewController - right?

Comment: nah, using inside your table view cell, which has UIImageView